# Silver vs Aluminum electrodes in silicon solar cells?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

In a typical high efficiency solar cell, silver is used as a front contact and aluminum as the rear contact. Despite the lower resistivity of silver, the usage of aluminum as a front contact would pose significant cost advantages.

Why is aluminum not used as a front contact? Is it due to the difficulty in preventing it from penetrating the p-n junction?

Comment: Silver is a much faster diffuser in silicon than Aluminum. But, aluminum will dope (at low levels).  Silver is chosen (in spite of being a mid-gap trap) to minimize the total area of top-side contacts while keeping resistance low.

Comment: You need an ohmic contact to n-Si, and an ohmic contact to p-Si. Can aluminum be both? I thought it could only be one of those (I forget which).

Comment: So to clarify: the use of Ag reduces shading and processing time. 

However, when considering an all-back contact cell, the reduced area advantage of Ag is eliminated and Al can be considered. And Si-doped Al allows for similar throughput as silver metallization?

Comment: Aluminum for backside is actually pretty sweet - you can coat the back with Al, heat until it starts to melt (nice eutectic), and then let resolidify - you get a p-type layer from the Al remaining in the Si a dopant, and a nice clean ohmic interface from the Al doped layer to the metal. For the top layer (n-type) you would need a Ti/TiN layer or some similar diffusion barrier to prevent the Al from doping, but you really need to prevent any Ag from getting in so it is a wash...